# How to Avoid being blocked on a Website that is being automated using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: firefox, selenium, automation, webdriver, profile

I'm automating a web page to check for broken links on that page. My code hits each 'href' on the webpage and check its response code. In this process, I'm hitting all the hrefs on the page in a short interval of time and as a result, the  internal links return 403 (Forbidden) status code (So I think that the website has blocked me for being a bot or spam! :( )

Any work around to avoid being blocked?

What I have tried so far (with no luck):

- doing a Thread.sleep() before a link is hit.
- accessing the website with a different user agent (firefox profiling).

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @peetya: When I try to hit  the internal links again, they return '403 (forbidden)' status code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below and update us.

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); **// here I gave it
                                  10 seconds, please change it as per your requirement**
```

Cheers!

Comment: @ user3872094  -  Thanks for your time. I have already tried this. No luck. The internal links of the web page are still returning the status code of 403 when I hit them and fetch their status code using 'getResponseCode();' method of 'HttpURLConnection'

Comment: @SantoshPillai, can you please share the link if you don't mind. So that it could be even helpful and easy.